# How to refresh w2ui grid to render a record value that is changed programmatically?

Tags: jquery, w2ui

I'm using w2ui v1.5 and have the following "design"

Html:

```
<body>
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%; height: 100vh"></div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
w2ui.myGrid.on('change',(event)=>{

    if(event.value_new !== event.value_previous) {
        const previousNote = event.value_previous;
        const updatedNote = event.value_new;
        const customId = event.recid;

        $.ajax({
            url:`/stuff/${customId}`,
            type:'PUT',
            contentType:'application/json',
            data:JSON.stringify({
                previousNote,
                updatedNote,
            })
        }).done((data, textStatus, xhr) => {
            console.log('DONE--->',data,'status',textStatus,'xhr',xhr); //NOOP
        }).fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)=>{
            conflictPopup(customId, xhr.responseJSON);
        });
    }
});
```

In the popup I try to revert to the old value after displaying details:

```
const conflictPopup = (customId, data) => {
  w2ui.myGrid.set(customId,{userNotes:data.previousNote}); //DOESN'T WORK

  w2popup.open({
    title: 'CONFLICT - STALE DATA',
    body: 'oops!',
    actions: {
        Ok(event) {
        //even this doesn't work
            w2popup.close();
            w2ui['myGrid'].set(customId,{userNotes: data.currentValue});
            w2ui['myGrid'].refresh();//(customId,'userNotes');
        }
    }
});
}
```

The grid continues to show the stale data. I even tried calling `w2ui.myGrid.refresh()` but to no avail. I even tried using `w2ui.myGrid.refreshCell(customId,data.previousNote)` and even that doesn't work.

No combination of calling `refresh` or manually triggering the event forces the UI to update. If I do `w2ui.myGrid.records` on the console, I see the data structure with the correct value of the `userNotes` but the grid doesn't seem to get refreshed even after calling that method on the console. What am I  missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for quite a while, I decided to do `event.preventDefault()` and manually set the values in the ajax callbacks. That seems to have worked:

```
const updateUserNote = (recordId, note) => w2ui.myGrid.set(recordId,{userNotes:note});
 
w2ui.myGrid.on('change',(event)=>{

    if(event.value_new !== event.value_previous) {
        const previousNote = event.value_previous;
        const updatedNote = event.value_new;
        const customId = event.recid;

        $.ajax({
            url:`/stuff/${customId}`,
            type:'PUT',
            contentType:'application/json',
            data:JSON.stringify({
                previousNote,
                updatedNote,
            })
        }).done((data, textStatus, xhr) => {
            console.log('DONE--->',data,'status',textStatus,'xhr',xhr); 
            updateUserNote(customId,updatedNote); //manually set
        }).fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)=>{
            conflictPopup(customId, xhr.responseJSON);
            updateUserNote(customId,xhr.responseJSON.newValue); //manually set
        });
    }
});
```